# JBoss6 MDB failing to deploy but deploys fine in JBoss4.0.4

Tags: jboss, hornetq, message-driven-bean, jboss-mdb

I'm trying to deploy a jar that I have in my JBoss-4.0.4.GA environment to a JBoss-6.0.0.Final environment. I have hit an issue that I'm not sure about. I am getting this error when starting JBoss:

```
17:45:27,719 INFO  [EjbDeployer] installing bean: ejb/#MyMessageBean,uid33175643
17:45:27,719 INFO  [EjbDeployer]   with dependencies:
17:45:27,719 INFO  [EjbDeployer]   and supplies:
17:45:27,738 INFO  [EjbDeployer]        jndi:null
17:45:27,796 INFO  [EjbModule] Deploying MyMessageBean
17:45:27,918 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=jboss.j2ee:jndiName=local/MyMessageBean@16788767,service=EJB state=Configured mode=Manual requiredState=Create: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Message driven beans are not bound into remote jndi
```

We are using ejb 2.1.

I imagine that there is something in my deployment descriptors that JBoss 4.0.4 was tolerant of, that JBoss 6 is not so tolerant of.

META-INF/ejb-jar.xml

```
<message-driven>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>My Message Bean</display-name>
    <ejb-name>MyMessageBean</ejb-name>
    <ejb-class>com.myplace.MyMessageBean</ejb-class>
    <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    <acknowledge-mode>Auto-acknowledge</acknowledge-mode>
    <message-driven-destination>
        <destination-type>javax.jms.Topic</destination-type>
        <subscription-durability>NonDurable</subscription-durability>
    </message-driven-destination>
</message-driven>
```

And META-INF/jboss.xml:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>MyMessageBean</ejb-name>
        <destination-jndi-name>topic/MyTopic</destination-jndi-name>
        <configuration-name>My Message Driven Bean Container Configuration</configuration-name>
    </message-driven>
</enterprise-beans>
```

My deployment descriptors are generated by xdoclet.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this one was odd - I removed the MetricsInterceptor from the container definition. The reported error doesn't seem related to the fix, but it's what made the difference. Hope this helps someone else.